# Xamarin Azure AD B2C login, stuck at login page

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to log into a xamarin mobile application using AAD B2C authentication. I have created the solution in visual studio. In Azure I have created my tenant, registered a native application and a web application (Properties below) and am trying to debug my application. Currently, I am redirected to the B2Clogin page and can enter a username and password. Then it processes the request and stays on that page indefinitely. When I check the azure portal, I can see the account I created through the B2C login page and I can see successful sign-ins but the B2C login page does not redirect back to my application.
I'm also using AuthenticationContinuationHelper in AppDelegate.cs as well as in MainActivity.cs

In App.cs

`````
````
     public static string B2CClientEndpoint = "<UserFlowAuthorizationEndpoint>"; //the endpoint generated when we ran the user flow.
            public static string[] B2CScopes = { "<RegisteredWebAPI.Read>" };

       PCAB2C = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(B2CClientID)
                    .WithB2CAuthority("https://<DirectoryName>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<DirectoryName>.onmicrosoft.com/<Policy>")
                    .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("<SecurityGroup>")
                    .WithRedirectUri("msal<ApplicationID>://auth")
                    .Build();

````
`````

In Controller class

`````
````C#

     IAccount User = Accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (Accounts.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        Result = await App.PCAB2C.AcquireTokenSilent(App.B2CScopes, User)
                       .WithB2CAuthority("<B2CSignInAuthority>")
                       .ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        User = Accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                        Result = await App.PCAB2C.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.B2CScopes)
                            .WithB2CAuthority("<B2CSignInAuthority>")
                            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                            .WithAccount(User)
                            .ExecuteAsync();
                    }

```
`````

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa) of AD B2C,

> To refresh and get tokens in a hidden iframe, use prompt=none to ensure that the iframe does not get stuck on the sign-in page, and returns immediately.

So essentially, verify your URL and don't forget to review the Error response!

Comment: I tried adding withprompt(prompt.noprompt) and still its not working, there is no change

Comment: Adding "&prompt=none" to the end of the URL didnt fix it?

Comment: I don't have the URL. The Xamarin methods format the URL automatically based on the options and send it in the method. Adding that property declaration does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and resolved it by reducing the minimum target Android & iOS versions.

ie: Android 8.0 and higher & iOS min 13.0

Apparently, MSAL has a min OS version to target in Xamarin Forms builds.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the link to what you mentioned - "Apparently, MSAL has a min OS version to target in Xamarin Forms builds."